# TCP connection breaks after 1 message

Tags: c++, networking, tcp

I have a project which i communicate with DNS servers. For example I used googles DNS server. After connecting to the server and sending a message, everything works well and the server returns an answer. But by the time i send the second query, the server already closed the connection by himself(sends FIN) and now I send a message to an invalid fd. Is there a known solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the DNS over TCP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7766):

> The server should assume that the client will initiate connection
> closing, and should delay closing its end of the connection until
> all outstanding client requests have been satisfied.

This means that if you send multiple requests simultaneously, the connection will stay open until all the requests have been replied to. *But* once there are no more pending requests, the connection can be closed.

If you want to make multiple requests, then you either need to send them all at once, or create new connections for each single request.